# Integrating GOOGLE LOGIN in my CodeIgniter 4 App failing when move to cPanel live Server

Tags: php, mysql, google-signin, codeigniter-4

Am new here, but i need your help please.

Through  couple of tutorials online, was able to get the **GOOGLE LOGIN** work perfectly on my Web App on my Xampp localhost server. But when I moved same code onto live Web App running on Linux Cpanel Server, got an error "**403.shtml is not a valid controller name**".

Here is the code.
**Controller** - Login.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\LoginModel;

class Login extends Controller
{

public $loginModel;
public $session;
public $email;
public $googleClient=NULL;
public function __construct(){
helper('form');
$this->loginModel = new LoginModel();
$this->session = session();
$this->email = \Config\Services::email();
include_once APPPATH.'Libraries/vendor/autoload.php';
$this->googleClient = new \Google_Client();

$this->googleClient->setClientId('clientID');
$this->googleClient->setClientSecret('SecretID');
$this->googleClient->setRedirectUri('https://example.net/login/gauth');
$this->googleClient->setAccessType('online');
$this->googleClient->addScope('email');
$this->googleClient->addScope('profile');

}

public function index()
{
$data = [];
//Here code for site login

//Google login button
$loginButton = '';
          if(!session()->set("AccessToken"))
          {
          $loginButton = $this->googleClient->createAuthUrl();
          $data['loginButton'] = $loginButton;
          return view('login', $data);
          }
          else
          {
          return view('login', $data);
          }

return view('login', $data);
echo view('includes/footer');
}

public function gauth()
{
    $session = session();

$token = $this->googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);

   
if(!isset($token['error'])){
$this->googleClient->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
session()->set("AccessToken", $token['access_token']);

$googleService = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($this->googleClient);
$data = $googleService->userinfo->get();
$currentDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


$userdata=array();
if($this->loginModel->google_user_exists($data['id']))
{

//User ALready Login and want to Login Again
$userdata = [
'verification_code'      => $data['id'],
'first_name'      => $data['given_name'],
            'last_name'        => $data['family_name'],
'email'            => $data['email'],
            'profile_pic'      => $data['picture'],
'last_modified'    => $currentDateTime
];
$this->loginModel->updateGoogleUser($userdata, $data['id']);
session()->set("logged_user", $userdata['verification_code']);

}
else
{
//new User want to Login
$userdata = [
'social_provider' => Google,
'status' => active,
'verification_code'      => $data['id'],
            'first_name'    => $data['given_name'],
            'last_name'    => $data['family_name'],
            'email'        => $data['email'],
            'profile_pic'  => $data['picture'],
'created_at'    => $currentDateTime
];
$this->loginModel->createGoogleUser($userdata);
}

session()->set("logged_user", $userdata['verification_code']);
}
else
{
    session()->setFlashData("Error", "Something went Wrong");
return redirect()->to(base_url());
}

//Successfull Login
return redirect()->to(base_url()."/home");
}
}
```

**View** - login.php

```
<div class="form-group">
<a href="<?= $loginButton ?>" class="form-control btn btn-danger rvn_obtn mt-3"><i class="bi bi-google px-3"></i> Login with Google</a>
</div>
```

Looking forward to hear from you

Comment: when you get 403 error? Does Index page gives error or only after google redirect?

Comment: @Ergec I get the error after coming from GOOGLE.

When I click on Button, am taken to either Choose an Account among my already signed in Google Accounts,

Comment: what is the URL in address bar after you come back from google? does that url exists? because it sounds like either your router is not configured properly or redirect url is wrong.

Comment: https://revisenow.net/login/gauth?code=4%2F0AX4XfWixxxxxx&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=none

Comment: @Ergec you can try it yourself on this link. I have temporarily activated the link [link](https://www.revisenow.net/login)

Comment: I get a `404` error on `/login/gauth` with `auth code` in address bar. It seems your router does not properly points to correct controller action to process code and do redirect.

Comment: I haven't configured a Route for this.  I added the link in google as it is from my Controller Login.php

However the /home is a route  as per code below in my **Login.php**
```**
//Successfull Login
return redirect()->to(base_url()."/home");**
```
Should I configure a Route for it like ** $routes->add('u/google', 'Login::gauth'); **

Comment: Ok problem is not router because /login/gauth gives "Invalid code" which is the error return by `fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode` when code is empty.

Comment: yes @Ergec.
Also i hinted earlier that in that code you get in browser, when you delete and leave only the URL and code. You will be registered and signed into the system.

Is there anything you can make of that? Thank you

Comment: **$token = $this->googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);**
From that code to DB is there anything we can change there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I simplified and tested your code and authentication works just fine. The problem is your user creation and/or redirection logic.

```
if (!isset($token['error'])) {
    $googleService = new \Google\Service\Oauth2($this->googleClient);
    $data = $googleService->userinfo->get();
    // Login Success
} else {
    // Login Failed
}
```

Comment: Hey @Ergec,Tried the above and got error ` Error 400: invalid_request 
Missing required parameter: scope`

Comment: I was in Google Documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2  . And they are mentioning "The application should store the refresh token for future use and use the access token to access a Google API. Once the access token expires, the application uses the refresh token to obtain a new one.". Am i missing the **refresh token** ?

Comment: That is irrelevant. I updated my answer. You service also works but it's deprecated. Better use new service.

Comment: I agree,  let me venture in google one tap sign in . Thanks for the help though.